# jQuery DataTables - Sorting a dummy column after the values have been modified

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I have a dataTable with a dummy column that is being populated after it is loaded. However, the modified column is not able to be sorted, as it seems to be sorting by the original value pulled from the database, which is just an empty string. I've tried modifying the data-order and data-sort values of the cell as well, but that didn't solve my issue. How can I indicate to the dataTable what the sort values of the cells are?

```
// initialize data table
$('#projects').dataTable( {
    "dom": "<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",
    "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    "columns": [
        { data: 'active', name: 'active' },
        { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
        { data: 'entry_count', name: 'entry_count' }
    ],
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "{{{ URL::to('admin/projects/data') }}}"
}).on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    // update dummy column data
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/projects/getEntryCount',
        success: function(data) {
            $("table").find('.entry_count').each(function(){
                $(this).html(data[$(this).attr("id")]);
                $(this).parent().attr("data-order",data[$(this).attr("id")]);
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Controller.php

```
// get table data
public function getData() {
    $projects = DB::table('project')
        ->select(array(
            'id',
            'active',
            'name'
        ));
    // add dummy columns for sorting
    $projects = $projects->addSelect(DB::raw("'' as entry_count"));

    return Datatables::of($projects)
       ->add_column('entry_count', '<p class="entry_count" id="entry_count_{{ $id }}"></p>')
       ->remove_column('id')
       ->make(true);
}
```